# How to export array data into xlsx in React

Tags: excel, reactjs

I am looking for a good library that allows us to export array data (table data) into a xlsx (excel) format. I also want to have options to display merged cell data and specify colors for cells.

I've been using `react-csv`, but it doesn't have an option to display merged cell data or change the color of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

One library, that from the looks of it supports it is [xlsx](https://sheetjs.com/pro).